# HttpListener vs HttpSelfHostServer WebApi

Tags: c#, webserver, asp.net-web-api2, httplistener

Writing an windows service using the .net framework (not dotnetcore) with c# that needs a web interface to manage it. No IIS or anything else installed other than the app to serve html files for the web interface - so need a webserver to serve static html files.

The static html file that will be served will call web api methods via javascript to query data and manage the internals of the service.

Already using self hosted web api with HttpSelfHostServer to write methods that can be queried via javascript using ApiController.

To serve the static html file I could do the following:

1. Use HttpListener to serve the static html file
2. Write a method in a ApiController that returns FileContent using HttpSelfHostServer and create a "index.html" route

Since they are just static files I could just HttpSelfHostServer and have a webapi method return the contents of the html file.

Not sure if there is a benefit of one over the other in this case.  Any thoughts?